# Como insertar imagenes en JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Llevo más de 3 hrs tratando de poner una simple imagen en un proyecto JSP, estoy recien aprendiendo a manejar esto, y necesito poner una imagen que tengo guardada en un directorio de mi pc.

He intentado hacerlo como si programara un html normalmente, pero en JSP cambian algunas cosas y la forma normal de hacerlo no sirve, ¿como puedo poner en el html de JSP que esta guardada en el Escritorio de mi pc?

He buscado tanto pero ninguna ayuda me sirve porque no entiendo absolutamente nada lo que explican o se van a bases de datos que no estoy usando eso. 
Tengo esto `<img src=  id="imagen">`, ¿qué debo poner en src para que se inserte bien la imagen? Por favor, explicación corta porque JSP nunca me lo explicaron en clases y me dieron que hacer un este trabajo, y solo he aprendido lo básico por YouTube.

Uso GlassFish como server

Answer (score 0):

para poder insertar una imagen en una pagina jsp puede hacer lo siguiente:

**1)** Crear un directorio o carpeta para imágenes dentro del proyecto:

[image: Estructura proyecto]

Como se puede observar hay un directorio llamado "**img**" allí estarían las imágenes.

2) Teniendo en cuenta la estructura anterior, en el jsp se insertaria la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="img/imagen.png" id="miImagen">
```

Tenga en cuenta que "**imagen.png**" debe estar dentro del directorio "**img**" y el archivo jsp debería estar por fuera. El atributo src define la ruta de la imagen, por otro lado el atributo "id" representa un valor único de identificación para el elemento.

Saludos.